# What will cpu do when a thread waiting for a mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm curious about the behavior of cpu during a thread waiting for a mutex. Now I can imagine two possibilities:

1. The cpu stay on the current thread and check if the mutex had been unlocked continually.
2. The cpu will switch to another thread(or process) for a moment and switch back to the origin thread and check temporary.
   Which one is right or the stl implement in another way?

Comment: This depends on the type of mutex used and which OS kernel you are running.

Comment: Option #2. The thread is paused and is wakened up when something happens to the mutex. To put it simply.

Comment: How would the mutex ever become unlocked if the CPU were kept busy with waiting for someone to unlock it?

Comment: A decent OS avoids busy waiting (spinning on a flag) as much as possible.

Comment: (This is a very system-specific question)  @molbdnilo interrupts such as those originating from the motherboard and its IO subsystem can wake up a sleeping CPU.  Minimally, if the system has a timer circuit connected to an interrupt pin on the cpu then it would be safe to halt fetching and executing instructions completely and only be awakened when the timer fires.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I am pretty sure molbdnilo was asking a leading question. ;-)

Comment: @molbdnilo, Some computers have more than one CPU. Under some circumstances, on a multi-CPU machine, it can make sense for one thread to "busy-wait" for a thread running on a different CPU to unlock a mutex. This is more often true when it's OS kernel code or embedded, real-time code that's waiting for the mutex.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this you first need to understand the difference between thread and cpu core. Thread is an abstract thing, a data structure, that is used to represent some sequence of operations to be executed. The OS assigns threads to cpu cores, and those cores then execute those operations. The OS (and also hardware) can also interrupt this execution at any time (although not in the middle of a single instruction), save such thread's state, suspend it, and assign some other thread to that core. This is also known as context switch. The OS sometimes does that on so called syscalls (when a program calls some OS's functionality, e.g. asks for the access to disk, network, etc.) as well. It is important because mutexes utilize some syscalls under the hood.

So what happens when a thread tries to access a locked mutex? First of all, no periodical checks happen. While possible, that would be a waste of cpu cycles and extremely unlikely that any serious OS does that. What actually happens is that each mutex internally has a queue associated. When it is locked, the OS will add current thread to this queue and will suspend it. Afterwards the OS will assign some other thread to this cpu core, if available.

Now if a mutex is locked, then there's a thread that actually locked that mutex. Let's call that thread an owner. This thread is not suspended, and it does some work. When it finishes whatever it is doing, it has to unlock the mutex (which is a syscall as well), otherwise those pending threads will never resume. When that (i.e. the unlocking) happens the OS will look at the associated queue, and pick a thread from it (which one is an implementation detail, it will often be some priority queue). This newly picked thread will be the new owner of the mutex, and the OS will resume it, meaning schedule the thread for execution. Schedule, because all cores may be busy at the moment.

Note that this is a brief overview of the topic. There are lots of other things and optimizations in play, like [futexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) and how to actually implement thread-safe (or rather core-safe) code without mutexes (these are not hardware features, mutexes are implemented in the OS). But that's more or less how things are.

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft world, the [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-mutex-objects) is waited on with [WaitForSingleObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject), which is described as

> If the object's state is nonsignaled, the calling thread enters the wait state until the object is signaled or the time-out interval elapses.

Now you need to know that the "wait state" is a state where the thread is not active. We call it "blocking", which is the opposite of a busy wait where CPU time is used.

At that beginning, the kernel will immediately give the CPU to another thread and never give it back to your thread, unless the Mutex is becoming "signaled". So it will really use 0 CPU cycles during the wait.

When the kernel notices that the Mutex has changed, it can "wake up" the thread and might even boost its priority because it was waiting friendly all the time.

> The cpu stay on the current thread and check if the mutex had been unlocked continually.

It's not the CPU that picks a thread to be executed. The thread scheduler of Windows will pick a thread that gets executed.

If a Mutex could block a CPU that way, you need to only 8 or 12 Mutexes to fully brick your system.

> The cpu will switch to another thread(or process) for a moment [...]

Almost. There will be an interrupt by a timer. The interrupt will be handled by an interrupt service routine by the Windows kernel. At that time, the kernel can decide which thread will be executed next.

> [...] and switch back to the origin thread and check temporary.

No. Because the Mutex is a kernel object, the kernel already knows that there's no used in letting the thread check again unless the Mutex has been signaled.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the thread will attempt to acquire the mutex, and if it can't (e.g. because another thread already acquired it) it will inform the scheduler and the scheduler will block the waiting thread and switch to a different thread, and then (later, when the lock is released) the scheduler will unblock the waiting thread and give it CPU time again.

On single-CPU systems; this is almost required. All CPU time spent (e.g. "spinning"/polling the lock again) between finding out the lock can't be acquired and doing a task switch (to a thread that may release the lock) is a waste of CPU time that will achieve nothing (because no other thread can release the lock until a task switch occurs).

However, research on multi-CPU systems (that I vaguely remember from about 20 years ago that may or may not have been done by Sun for Solaris) indicates that a small amount of "spinning" (in the hope that a thread running on a different CPU releases the lock in time) can be beneficial (by avoiding the cost of task switch/es). My intuition is that "time spent spinning before blocking" should be roughly equal to the cost of a task switch (or, if a task switch costs 123 microseconds, it'd probably be worthwhile spinning for 123 microseconds before the scheduler is told to block your thread); but this would depend heavily on scenario (e.g. how heavily contended the lock is, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Typically,

3. The hardware thread (your "CPU") will be switched to running a different software thread by the kernel, and the original software thread will be set aside until the mutex it is waiting on becomes signaled. At that point the kernel will place it among the set of software threads that it seeks to schedule for execution on one of the hardware threads in the system.

Your option 1 applies to what is called a *critical section* on Microsoft's platforms and more generally a *spinlock*. See `pthread_spin_lock()`.

Your option 2 is most similar to what usually happens.